# from non perl programer

Tags: perl

Any perl expert can help me to understand this block of perl code

```
  $a=18;
$b=55;
$c=16;
$d=88;
$mtk = {
    'A'     => [$a, $b],
     'M'   => [$c, $d]

    };
```

is this dictionary hold char and pair and how to access key and values 
thanks a lot

Comment: Reading about [Perl data structures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html), should help you as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$a`, `$b`, `$c`, and `$d` are [scalars](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values). `$mtk` is a [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) to a [hash of arrayrefs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS). You can access it like:

```
print $mtk->{A}[0]; ## 18
```

I'd suggest the book [*Learning Perl*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do) if you are just getting started and struggling with this code.

[perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is a hash ref for array refs as values. Here is a traverse code below:

```
for my $key (sort keys %$mtk) {
    print "Current key is $key\n";
    for my $val (@{ $mtk->{$key} }) {
        print "... and one of value is $val\n";
    }
}
```

The output will be

```
Current key is A
... and one of value is 18
... and one of value is 55
Current key is M
... and one of value is 16
... and one of value is 88
```